# Started/Bound service lifecycle. Why is it re-created

Tags: android, service, android-service, lifecycle

In my app I have a sticky service which is started via startService() in onCreate() of my Application subclass. I then bind to that service to interact with it. All seems to be fine here: I can exit the app (finish()) or I can press Home key and when I get back to the app I can still re-connect to the same service running in background.

But there is one use case that puzzles me. If I press Home key, then go launch some other apps, watch YouTube etc., after a while I can see in the logs that my Application is re-created (onCreate() is called), which is fine. But, when I try to bind to the same service now, it gets re-created too (constructor is called), and I get a new instance, although I'm checking and I'm sure my old service is still running. This breaks the use case, because I need the data being processed in the service which is already running.

Isn't bindService() supposed to bind to existing service and only create it if it's not running? Why is it causing a new instance to be created? And in general, where is the flow for this use case (Application being re-created while in background) is described?

P.S. Another strange thing is that onDestroy() of old service is not called.

here is some code of my Application class for context:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);
    if(!isMyServiceRunning()){
        getContext().startService(intent);
    }
    getContext.bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your app to be connected to the one instance of the service set

```
android:singleUser="true"
```

in the service description in AndroidManifest.xml. This flag if set to true means that a single instance of this component will run for all users.

Also you may found useful in your case to use

```
android:stopWithTask="false"
```

This means that your service will stay active even if the task with your app is destroyed.

Comment: I just looked up `stopWithTask`, and [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#stopWithTask) says the default value is `false`, so setting it to `false` probably isn't needed.

Comment: I just looked up `singleUser`, and [the documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multiuser-apps) says `Only system apps can currently use this feature.`. I haven't tried it myself, though, so I could be wrong.